# Installing Windows in a laptop with a dysfunctional display

Tags: windows, laptop, display, reinstall

My laptop's display does not work. I am currently using an external LCD screen. So when I power up my laptop I can't see anything. Only after the windows logon screen is displayed, the screen shows up on the Monitor.
 I need to re-install Windows. How do I go about it? 
PS: My laptop is a HP-dv6

Comment: Have you actually tried reinstalling yet using the LCD screen?

Comment: No. I haven't. It is my calculated guess that the LCD wouldn't be detected. Because the first time I used the LCD, I had to manually select the option to use the LCD

Comment: By default the display should be mirrored. Try it.

Comment: Try pressing `[F10]` at boot up for BIOS settings.

Comment: Without being able to see the BIOS screens, I would not try reinstalling.

Comment: @fstx, That is exactly my worry. Any suggestions apart from buying a new laptop?

Comment: 1) Try pressing F10 repeatedly when you start the computer, and then try the screen-switching keys to get a picture on the external monitor.

Comment: 2) Check if there is a program to change your BIOS settings from windows, and look for settings related to teh external screen.

Comment: 3) Taking it apart, reseat the screen connectors and put it together again.

Comment: 4) Put in a new hard disk and try installing to that.

Comment: 5) Install to a new harddisk using a different computer, then sysprep the disk and putting it your laptop.

Comment: That's a whole bunch of ideas there. I shall try em and get back. Thanks a ton